# Why my Jetpack Compose Text does not recomposed while TextField does

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, compose-recomposition

In Android Jetpack Compose app, I have tried a clickable update on Text.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent { ColorBox() }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ColorBox() {
    val zero = 0
    val full = 255
    var r by remember { mutableStateOf(zero) }
    var g by remember { mutableStateOf(full) }
    var b by remember { mutableStateOf(zero) }
    val color = Color(r,g,b)
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color)
            .clickable {
                val until = 256
                r = Random.nextInt(until)
                g = Random.nextInt(until)
                b = Random.nextInt(until)
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        Column {
            Text(text = "R:$r, G:$g, B:$b")
            TextField(value = "R:$r, G:$g, B:$b", onValueChange = {})
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the screen, the background color changes.
I expect both Text and TextField change with respect to the color RGB components.
But Text didn't change while TextField changed as expected, as shown in the image below.

[image: after click, the color changed but Text does not update]

Doesn't Text Composable run recomposition, and why does not?

Comment: What do you mean, your code is fine, and the text will be reorganized with RGB changes

Comment: I'm sorry, the Random setup is confusing. I'll update the code and add a screenshot.

Comment: I suspect it is a problem with your compose version, because your code is completely correct when I compile and run it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was version dependency of UI, thanks @Halifax.

Project: build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
//        compose_ui_version = '1.1.1'
        compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'  // -- (*)
    }
}
```

Module: build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
//    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'  // -- (*)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
}
```

The version combination marked `// -- (*)` causes the above problem.